# How to create a new function in MediaWiki? - not an extension

Tags: php, function, mediawiki

In MediaWiki, I would like to create a new function, called getFooterLinks2, instead of the getFooterLinks function, which is located in the VectorTemplate.php file of the Vector skin.

Also, I am interested that the function will print data from the database and I do not want to do so as an extension.

What files, functions, and steps should I do? I've been developing PHP for over a decade, but not quite familiar with the way MediaWiki works

I tried to find a guide to explain where MediaWiki is calling its functions, but I got lost, no matter which guide I read and how much I dug on the net.

This is the code that is now there:

```
<?php
    foreach ( $this->getFooterLinks() as $category => $links ) {
?>
<ul id="footer-<?php echo $category ?>">
<?php
    foreach ( $links as $link ) {
?>
         <li id="footer-<?php echo $category ?>-<?php echo $link ?>"><?php $this->html( $link ) ?></li>
<?php
    }
?>
</ul>
```

And this is the full code of the file:

```
<?php
/**
 * QuickTemplate subclass for Vector
 * @ingroup Skins
 */
class VectorTemplate extends BaseTemplate {
    /* Functions */

    /**
     * Outputs the entire contents of the (X)HTML page
     */
    public function execute() {
        $this->data['namespace_urls'] = $this->data['content_navigation']['namespaces'];
        $this->data['view_urls'] = $this->data['content_navigation']['views'];
        $this->data['action_urls'] = $this->data['content_navigation']['actions'];
        $this->data['variant_urls'] = $this->data['content_navigation']['variants'];

        // Move the watch/unwatch star outside of the collapsed "actions" menu to the main "views" menu
        if ( $this->config->get( 'VectorUseIconWatch' ) ) {
            $mode = $this->getSkin()->getUser()->isWatched( $this->getSkin()->getRelevantTitle() )
                ? 'unwatch'
                : 'watch';

            if ( isset( $this->data['action_urls'][$mode] ) ) {
                $this->data['view_urls'][$mode] = $this->data['action_urls'][$mode];
                unset( $this->data['action_urls'][$mode] );
            }
        }
        $this->data['pageLanguage'] =
            $this->getSkin()->getTitle()->getPageViewLanguage()->getHtmlCode();

        // Output HTML Page
        $this->html( 'headelement' );
        ?>
        <div id="mw-page-base" class="noprint"></div>
        <div id="mw-head-base" class="noprint"></div>
        <div id="content" class="mw-body" role="main">
            <a id="top"></a>
            <?php
            if ( $this->data['sitenotice'] ) {
                echo Html::rawElement( 'div',
                    [
                        'id' => 'siteNotice',
                        'class' => 'mw-body-content',
                    ],
                    // Raw HTML
                    $this->get( 'sitenotice' )
                );
            }
            if ( is_callable( [ $this, 'getIndicators' ] ) ) {
                echo $this->getIndicators();
            }
            // Loose comparison with '!=' is intentional, to catch null and false too, but not '0'
            if ( $this->data['title'] != '' ) {
                echo Html::rawElement( 'h1',
                    [
                        'id' => 'firstHeading',
                        'class' => 'firstHeading',
                        'lang' => $this->get( 'pageLanguage' ),
                    ],
                    // Raw HTML
                    $this->get( 'title' )
                );
            }

            $this->html( 'prebodyhtml' );
            ?>
            <div id="bodyContent" class="mw-body-content">
                <?php
                if ( $this->data['isarticle'] ) {
                    echo Html::element( 'div',
                        [
                            'id' => 'siteSub',
                            'class' => 'noprint',
                        ],
                        $this->getMsg( 'tagline' )->text()
                    );
                }
                ?>
                <div id="contentSub"<?php $this->html( 'userlangattributes' ) ?>><?php
                    $this->html( 'subtitle' )
                ?></div>
                <?php
                if ( $this->data['undelete'] ) {
                    echo Html::rawElement( 'div',
                        [ 'id' => 'contentSub2' ],
                        // Raw HTML
                        $this->get( 'undelete' )
                    );
                }
                if ( $this->data['newtalk'] ) {
                    echo Html::rawElement( 'div',
                        [ 'class' => 'usermessage' ],
                        // Raw HTML
                        $this->get( 'newtalk' )
                    );
                }
                // Keep this empty `div` for compatibility with gadgets and user scripts
                // using this place to insert extra elements before.
                echo Html::element( 'div', [ 'id' => 'jump-to-nav' ] );
                ?>
                <a class="mw-jump-link" href="#mw-head"><?php $this->msg( 'vector-jumptonavigation' ) ?></a>
                <a class="mw-jump-link" href="#p-search"><?php $this->msg( 'vector-jumptosearch' ) ?></a>
                <?php
                $this->html( 'bodycontent' );

                if ( $this->data['printfooter'] ) {
                    ?>
                    <div class="printfooter">
                        <?php $this->html( 'printfooter' ); ?>
                    </div>
                <?php
                }

                if ( $this->data['catlinks'] ) {
                    $this->html( 'catlinks' );
                }

                if ( $this->data['dataAfterContent'] ) {
                    $this->html( 'dataAfterContent' );
                }
                ?>
                <div class="visualClear"></div>
                <?php $this->html( 'debughtml' ); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="mw-navigation">
            <h2><?php $this->msg( 'navigation-heading' ) ?></h2>
            <div id="mw-head">
                <?php $this->renderNavigation( [ 'PERSONAL' ] ); ?>
                <div id="left-navigation">
                    <?php $this->renderNavigation( [ 'NAMESPACES', 'VARIANTS' ] ); ?>
                </div>
                <div id="right-navigation">
                    <?php $this->renderNavigation( [ 'VIEWS', 'ACTIONS', 'SEARCH' ] ); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="mw-panel">
                <div id="p-logo" role="banner"><a class="mw-wiki-logo" href="<?php
                    echo htmlspecialchars( $this->data['nav_urls']['mainpage']['href'] )
                    ?>" <?php
                    echo Xml::expandAttributes( Linker::tooltipAndAccesskeyAttribs( 'p-logo' ) )
                    ?>></a></div>
                <?php $this->renderPortals( $this->data['sidebar'] ); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php Hooks::run( 'VectorBeforeFooter' ); ?>
        <?php /** ssss */ ?>
                   <div id="footer" role="contentinfo"<?php $this->html( 'userlangattributes' ) ?>>
            <?php
            foreach ( $this->getFooterLinks() as $category => $links ) {
            ?>
            <ul>
<?php foreach ( $this->getFooterLinks( 'flat' ) as $key ) { ?>
    <li><?php $this->html( $key ) ?></li>

<?php } ?>
</ul>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
            <?php $footericons = $this->getFooterIcons( 'icononly' );
            if ( count( $footericons ) > 0 ) {
                ?>
                <ul id="footer-icons" class="noprint">
                    <?php
                    foreach ( $footericons as $blockName => $footerIcons ) {
                    ?>
                    <li id="footer-<?php echo htmlspecialchars( $blockName ); ?>ico">
                        <?php
                        foreach ( $footerIcons as $icon ) {
                            echo $this->getSkin()->makeFooterIcon( $icon );
                        }
                        ?>
                    </li>
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </ul>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        </div>
                <?php /** ssse*/ ?>
        <?php $this->printTrail(); ?>

    </body>
</html>
<?php
    }

    /**
     * Render a series of portals
     *
     * @param array $portals
     */
    protected function renderPortals( array $portals ) {
        // Force the rendering of the following portals
        if ( !isset( $portals['TOOLBOX'] ) ) {
            $portals['TOOLBOX'] = true;
        }
        if ( !isset( $portals['LANGUAGES'] ) ) {
            $portals['LANGUAGES'] = true;
        }
        // Render portals
        foreach ( $portals as $name => $content ) {
            if ( $content === false ) {
                continue;
            }

            // Numeric strings gets an integer when set as key, cast back - T73639
            $name = (string)$name;

            switch ( $name ) {
                case 'SEARCH':
                    break;
                case 'TOOLBOX':
                    $this->renderPortal( 'tb', $this->getToolbox(), 'toolbox', 'SkinTemplateToolboxEnd' );
                    Hooks::run( 'VectorAfterToolbox' );
                    break;
                case 'LANGUAGES':
                    if ( $this->data['language_urls'] !== false ) {
                        $this->renderPortal( 'lang', $this->data['language_urls'], 'otherlanguages' );
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    $this->renderPortal( $name, $content );
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param string $name
     * @param array|string $content
     * @param null|string $msg
     * @param null|string|array $hook
     */
    protected function renderPortal( $name, $content, $msg = null, $hook = null ) {
        if ( $msg === null ) {
            $msg = $name;
        }
        $msgObj = $this->getMsg( $msg );
        $labelId = Sanitizer::escapeIdForAttribute( "p-$name-label" );
        ?>
        <div class="portal" role="navigation" id="<?php
        echo htmlspecialchars( Sanitizer::escapeIdForAttribute( "p-$name" ) )
        ?>"<?php
        echo Linker::tooltip( 'p-' . $name )
        ?> aria-labelledby="<?php echo htmlspecialchars( $labelId ) ?>">
            <h3<?php $this->html( 'userlangattributes' ) ?> id="<?php echo htmlspecialchars( $labelId )
                ?>"><?php
                echo htmlspecialchars( $msgObj->exists() ? $msgObj->text() : $msg );
                ?></h3>
            <div class="body">
                <?php
                if ( is_array( $content ) ) {
                ?>
                <ul>
                    <?php
                    foreach ( $content as $key => $val ) {
                        echo $this->makeListItem( $key, $val );
                    }
                    if ( $hook !== null ) {
                        // Avoid PHP 7.1 warning
                        $skin = $this;
                        Hooks::run( $hook, [ &$skin, true ] );
                    }
                    ?>
                </ul>
                <?php
                } else {
                    // Allow raw HTML block to be defined by extensions
                    echo $content;
                }

                $this->renderAfterPortlet( $name );
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php
    }

    /**
     * Render one or more navigations elements by name, automatically reversed by css
     * when UI is in RTL mode
     *
     * @param array $elements
     */
    protected function renderNavigation( array $elements ) {
        // Render elements
        foreach ( $elements as $name => $element ) {
            switch ( $element ) {
                case 'NAMESPACES':
                    ?>
                    <div id="p-namespaces" role="navigation" class="vectorTabs<?php
                    if ( count( $this->data['namespace_urls'] ) == 0 ) {
                        echo ' emptyPortlet';
                    }
                    ?>" aria-labelledby="p-namespaces-label">
                        <h3 id="p-namespaces-label"><?php $this->msg( 'namespaces' ) ?></h3>
                        <ul<?php $this->html( 'userlangattributes' ) ?>>
                            <?php
                            foreach ( $this->data['namespace_urls'] as $key => $item ) {
                                echo $this->makeListItem( $key, $item, [
                                    'vector-wrap' => true,
                                ] );
                            }
                            ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    break;
                case 'VARIANTS':
                    ?>
                    <div id="p-variants" role="navigation" class="vectorMenu<?php
                    if ( count( $this->data['variant_urls'] ) == 0 ) {
                        echo ' emptyPortlet';
                    }
                    ?>" aria-labelledby="p-variants-label">
                        <?php
                        // Replace the label with the name of currently chosen variant, if any
                        $variantLabel = $this->getMsg( 'variants' )->text();
                        foreach ( $this->data['variant_urls'] as $item ) {
                            if ( isset( $item['class'] ) && stripos( $item['class'], 'selected' ) !== false ) {
                                $variantLabel = $item['text'];
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        ?>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="vectorMenuCheckbox" aria-labelledby="p-variants-label" />
                        <h3 id="p-variants-label">
                            <span><?php echo htmlspecialchars( $variantLabel ) ?></span>
                        </h3>
                        <div class="menu">
                            <ul>
                                <?php
                                foreach ( $this->data['variant_urls'] as $key => $item ) {
                                    echo $this->makeListItem( $key, $item );
                                }
                                ?>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    break;
                case 'VIEWS':
                    ?>
                    <div id="p-views" role="navigation" class="vectorTabs<?php
                    if ( count( $this->data['view_urls'] ) == 0 ) {
                        echo ' emptyPortlet';
                    }
                    ?>" aria-labelledby="p-views-label">
                        <h3 id="p-views-label"><?php $this->msg( 'views' ) ?></h3>
                        <ul<?php $this->html( 'userlangattributes' ) ?>>
                            <?php
                            foreach ( $this->data['view_urls'] as $key => $item ) {
                                echo $this->makeListItem( $key, $item, [
                                    'vector-wrap' => true,
                                    'vector-collapsible' => true,
                                ] );
                            }
                            ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    break;
                case 'ACTIONS':
                    ?>
                    <div id="p-cactions" role="navigation" class="vectorMenu<?php
                    if ( count( $this->data['action_urls'] ) == 0 ) {
                        echo ' emptyPortlet';
                    }
                    ?>" aria-labelledby="p-cactions-label">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="vectorMenuCheckbox" aria-labelledby="p-cactions-label" />
                        <h3 id="p-cactions-label"><span><?php
                            $this->msg( 'vector-more-actions' )
                        ?></span></h3>
                        <div class="menu">
                            <ul<?php $this->html( 'userlangattributes' ) ?>>
                                <?php
                                foreach ( $this->data['action_urls'] as $key => $item ) {
                                    echo $this->makeListItem( $key, $item );
                                }
                                ?>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    break;
                case 'PERSONAL':
                    ?>
                    <div id="p-personal" role="navigation" class="<?php
                    if ( count( $this->data['personal_urls'] ) == 0 ) {
                        echo ' emptyPortlet';
                    }
                    ?>" aria-labelledby="p-personal-label">
                        <h3 id="p-personal-label"><?php $this->msg( 'personaltools' ) ?></h3>
                        <ul<?php $this->html( 'userlangattributes' ) ?>>
                            <?php
                            $notLoggedIn = '';

                            if ( !$this->getSkin()->getUser()->isLoggedIn() &&
                                User::groupHasPermission( '*', 'edit' )
                            ) {
                                $notLoggedIn =
                                    Html::element( 'li',
                                        [ 'id' => 'pt-anonuserpage' ],
                                        $this->getMsg( 'notloggedin' )->text()
                                    );
                            }

                            $personalTools = $this->getPersonalTools();

                            $langSelector = '';
                            if ( array_key_exists( 'uls', $personalTools ) ) {
                                $langSelector = $this->makeListItem( 'uls', $personalTools[ 'uls' ] );
                                unset( $personalTools[ 'uls' ] );
                            }

                            echo $langSelector;
                            echo $notLoggedIn;
                            foreach ( $personalTools as $key => $item ) {
                                echo $this->makeListItem( $key, $item );
                            }
                            ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    break;
                case 'SEARCH':
                    ?>
                    <div id="p-search" role="search">
                        <h3<?php $this->html( 'userlangattributes' ) ?>>
                            <label for="searchInput"><?php $this->msg( 'search' ) ?></label>
                        </h3>
                        <form action="<?php $this->text( 'wgScript' ) ?>" id="searchform">
                            <div<?php echo $this->config->get( 'VectorUseSimpleSearch' ) ? ' id="simpleSearch"' : '' ?>>
                                <?php
                                echo $this->makeSearchInput( [ 'id' => 'searchInput' ] );
                                echo Html::hidden( 'title', $this->get( 'searchtitle' ) );
                                /* We construct two buttons (for 'go' and 'fulltext' search modes),
                                 * but only one will be visible and actionable at a time (they are
                                 * overlaid on top of each other in CSS).
                                 * * Browsers will use the 'fulltext' one by default (as it's the
                                 *   first in tree-order), which is desirable when they are unable
                                 *   to show search suggestions (either due to being broken or
                                 *   having JavaScript turned off).
                                 * * The mediawiki.searchSuggest module, after doing tests for the
                                 *   broken browsers, removes the 'fulltext' button and handles
                                 *   'fulltext' search itself; this will reveal the 'go' button and
                                 *   cause it to be used.
                                 */
                                echo $this->makeSearchButton(
                                    'fulltext',
                                    [ 'id' => 'mw-searchButton', 'class' => 'searchButton mw-fallbackSearchButton' ]
                                );
                                echo $this->makeSearchButton(
                                    'go',
                                    [ 'id' => 'searchButton', 'class' => 'searchButton' ]
                                );
                                ?>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <?php

                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function makeLink( $key, $item, $options = [] ) {
        $html = parent::makeLink( $key, $item, $options );
        // Add an extra wrapper because our CSS is weird
        if ( isset( $options['vector-wrap'] ) && $options['vector-wrap'] ) {
            $html = Html::rawElement( 'span', [], $html );
        }
        return $html;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function makeListItem( $key, $item, $options = [] ) {
        // For fancy styling of watch/unwatch star
        if (
            $this->config->get( 'VectorUseIconWatch' )
            && ( $key === 'watch' || $key === 'unwatch' )
        ) {
            $item['class'] = rtrim( 'icon ' . $item['class'], ' ' );
            $item['primary'] = true;
        }

        // Add CSS class 'collapsible' to links which are not marked as "primary"
        if (
            isset( $options['vector-collapsible'] ) && $options['vector-collapsible'] ) {
            $item['class'] = rtrim( 'collapsible ' . $item['class'], ' ' );
        }

        // We don't use this, prevent it from popping up in HTML output
        unset( $item['redundant'] );

        return parent::makeListItem( $key, $item, $options );
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want the function to do? What data do you want to print from the database, and where do you want to print it to? Do you want to change how the footer looks?

Comment: I do not want to mess with the look of the footer, I can easily do with the help of CSS. I want to edit the sites in it. Add and Remove links from it.

I could not find where the sites in the footer are printed. So I decided to simply create a function that would bypass it, so that I would have more control over it.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use the built in configuration options as mentioned [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Footer), otherwise I'm not sure what other functionality you want "control" over.

**To add a new link** put this in `LocalSettings.php`:

```
$wgHooks['SkinTemplateOutputPageBeforeExec'][] = function($sk, &$tpl) {
    $tpl->set( 'termsofuse', $sk->footerLink('termsofuse', 'termsofusepage'));
    $tpl->data['footerlinks']['places'][] = 'termsofuse';
    return true;
};
```

It doesn't matter what you use for `termsofuse` and `termsofusepage` as long as you remember them. After you have done this create a new page on your wiki titled `MediaWiki:termsofuse` and enter into that page what you want the links text to be. Also create a page titled `MediaWiki:termsofusepage` and enter into that page the name of the page you want to link to direct you to, for example if you want to go to the main page write `Main_Page`.

**To remove the default links**:

Create an empty page at `MediaWiki:Privacy`

Create an empty page at `MediaWiki:Disclaimers`

**Order**:

They should be in the order you add them in, however default links are added first so will be before your custom ones. You could get around this (If you want default links) by recreating the default links as custom ones with same functionality.

Comment: Thanks Dylan, I've read this document before. But I did not understand it and I still do not understand it. If I understand it, it might have helped me.

And maybe through it, I could create a separate file to manage the footer menu, but I feel that this document requires a prior understanding of the way MediaWiki works, and exactly there I got lost.

Can you please explain to me where to put each line of code and what functions are available to remove and add links to the footer menu?

Comment: If you were able to tell me exactly what you want to do to the footer It would mean I could give you the exact answer you need.

Comment: In any footer menu, when you install MediaWiki, there are three default sites:
1) Privacy. 2) About. 3) Disclaimer. I want to edit the sites in it, according to my needs. 

For example: remove the Privacy and the Disclaimer, leave the page about and add a few more links to sites and pages I need to have in it, and in the order that I want it to be.